# Android Application idea how to achieve this

Tags: android

I want to create an android app.which is very unique. i want this app to connect to any kind of energy be it bad or good..my main motive is to connect my app to ghosts and spirits..so that it can become an interface between humans and spirits...i mean if that app is installed in any person's phone than the app should get connected to that person's soul....
  I have no idea how to achieve the same animation effect we see in the android foxnews application. After displaying the splash screen, the view of the main activity is smoothly displayed. I would like to have the same animation between my splash screen and my dashboard activity.

Comment: Black Magic is prohibited as per Google terms and conditions.

Comment: This question is still valid if you ignore the first paragraph. He is asking about animation. :P

Comment: Good luck with your app. Creating a good tranisition animation is the first step in smartphone-soul interfacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post features how to change Android’s default animation when switching between Activities. Before reading the rest, please know that the code that changes the standard animation be found at the API Demo that comes with the Android SDK. But since there’s a lack of proper documentation regarding this subject and it’s difficult to find a place explaining it, here is a post that helps in aiding these two problems. So, the code to change the animation between two Activities is very simple: just call the `overridePendingTransition()` from the current `Activity`, after starting a new `Intent`. This method is available from Android version 2.0 (API level 5), and it takes two parameters, that are used to define the enter and exit animations of your current `Activity`.

```
//Calls a new Activity  
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));  

//Set the transition -> method available from Android 2.0 and beyond  
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in,R.anim.push_up_out);
```

These two parameters are resource IDs for animations defined with XML files (one for each animation). These files have to be placed inside the app’s res/anim folder. Examples of these files can be found at the Android API demo, inside the anim folder. Let’s take a look at one of these files (push_left_in.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>  
  <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />  
</set>
```